# Stack: return address

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, return

Is return address on the stack the same as the value of program counter before a function was called? They both seem to relate to the same concept, i.e. to the next instruction that is going to be executed after the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The calling mechanism works like this (it may not work exactly this way, because different x86 architectures have different microarchitectures, but this "algorithm" gives the gist):

As the call instruction is <s>fetched</s>executed, `RIP` is ephemerally set to the address of the instruction following the call. The execution of `call` will push the value of `RIP` onto the stack, then it will set `RIP` to the resolved address of the target of the `call`.

Details [in the official manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf) in Volume 1, Chapter 6.

Comment: I'd be surprised if one could witness that behavior by single stepping.

Comment: That's _exactly_ why I said that is how it would behave, not how it actually behaves....

Comment: Ok. I had to check the meaning of _ephemerally_: lasting for a brief time. In this case as an internal state.

Comment: Yep. The published algorithm in the Intel Guide is 7 pages long, beginning on page 3-118 of Volume 2A. It references the value `tempEIP` which is of course nothing but a variable, but could be taken to "be" the program counter...only as you surmise, it is internal only and never accessible to the user program.

Comment: It's useful to talk about what happens to the architectural state, because all implementations must produce the same observable behaviour (other than timing).  One error though: s/fetched/executed/.  Even in very simple CPUs, instruction fetch happens a pipeline stage or two ahead of execution.  What matters is EIP/RIP as `call` executes, not as it's fetched & decoded.

Comment: Thanks Ray! Could you please comment on why there is a need to store the program counter before a function call, if the return address will essentially be the same thing?

Comment: The call instruction changes the program counter to the address of the called function and program execution continues there. The program counter eventually reaches the return instruction in the called function. At that point the return address (the address of the next instruction after the call instruction) is popped off the stack and loaded into the program counter. Program execution continues from there.